# Why can't I source function definitions into .bashrc read by .profile?

Tags: bash, profile

I have 3 config files: `.bashrc` sources `.bashrc_common`, and `.profile` sources `.bashrc`. Unfortunately, upon login to Gnome I get an error message saying that in `.bashrc` command `foo` was not found. But if `foo` is defined in a file sourced by `.bashrc`, why would it not be found?

```
# .profile

if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

```
# .bashrc_common

function foo {
    echo "foo $1"
}
```

```
# .bashrc

source $HOME/.bashrc_common
#.....
foo "hello"
```

Note that `foo` is available just fine everywhere in my terminal bash shells, it's just the Ubuntu login that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The file I was sourcing from .bashrc had an explicit guard that prevented it from running when invoked non-interactively. The moral of the story is -- if you encounter issues with config files launched by Gnome, double-check that they don't have any explicit "only run in interactive shells" checks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your GNOME is running a login shell instead of an interactive non-login shell reason why your **bashrc** is not sourced.

Just append to the end of **bash_login** the following :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```